# Playing base64 webm audio on Safari

Tags: safari, html5-audio, webm

I've tried a bunch of things to no avail. Setting the `src` of an audio element to the following base64 webm dataurl snippet and playing it works in most browsers, but is failing in Safari. Pasting the snippet in the location bar even works in Chrome.

https://gist.github.com/mayorbyrne/99e47f58eefcfe72e84e3e320d136c2c#file-gistfile1-txt

I *am* able to play a base64 encoded mp3 dataurl, as the following fiddle I found in another response works: https://www.jsfiddle.net/apo299od -- In addition, I've tried replacing the beginning of the snippet `data:audio/webm` with `data:audio/mp3` (works in Chrome, etc), and that moves me further along, but the audio doesn't actually play, it just flashes the audio symbol in the browser for a quick second.

Just wondering if I am spinning my wheels here, or if there is a way to get this snippet playing in an audio element on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS doesn't support the Vorbis / Opus audio codecs in WebM and on desktop only via third-party extensions like the VLC Web Browser plugin. Safari on iOS 11+ / macOS High Sierra+ can play Opus only if it's in a CAF container.

> **Note**: Safari on iOS supports low-complexity AAC audio, MP3 audio, AIF audio, WAVE audio, and baseline profile MPEG-4 video. Safari on the desktop (Mac OS X and Windows) supports all media supported by the installed version of QuickTime, including any installed third-party codecs

source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html

Comment: That's what I figured. If there was a way to convert that webm dataurl to an mp3 dataurl, that would help me....do you know a way to convert that base64 webm dataUrl above to an mp3 dataUrl client-side? I was trying with the  https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs library but to no avail.

Comment: I've got a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/mayorbyrne/but5dypj/ -- I've got it generating an mp3 of SOME sort. It's just playing a quick bit of static though.

Answer (score 0):

Safari can support Ogg Opus files with WebAssembly decoding.  You can see the demo and code below.  Not as simple as using an `<audio>` element, but you will get faster, low-latency playback using the Web Audio API:

https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-stream-audio